# Merging PHP array adding key

Tags: php, arrays

Ok, this question was probably asked many times here. Tried searching for a way that works but I dont find the correct term to search it.

I have following 2 array

Array 1

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [data] => DFF022
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [data] => DFF026
        )

)
```

Array 2

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => INC0000002
            [ia] => 
            [description] => Printer not working
            [state] => Monitoring - Waiting for Client
            [updated] => 12/30/2020 19.09.01
            [opened] => 12/24/2020 20.35.36
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => INC0000003
            [ia] => 
            [description] => Monitor broke down
            [state] => Pending - Awaiting Change Approval/Implementation
            [updated] => 12/29/2020 23.57.06
            [opened] => 12/29/2020 08.21.38
        )

)
```

Now the number of item inside the array is always will be same. If array 1 got 10 items, then array 2 will have 10 items as well.
I'm looking a way to merge the array to something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => INC1879727
            [ia] => 
            [description] => Unable to replay CME NS message
            [state] => Monitoring - Waiting for Client
            [updated] => 12/30/2020 19.09.01
            [opened] => 12/24/2020 20.35.36
            [data] => DFF022
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => INC1884171
            [ia] => 
            [description] => mw_uat - UAT00MSV_LNP6_01_pga_aggregate_limit
            [state] => Pending - Awaiting Change Approval/Implementation
            [updated] => 12/29/2020 23.57.06
            [opened] => 12/29/2020 08.21.38
            [data] => DFF026
        )

)
```

Any idea on how to accomplish this?
Using array merge or combine just combines the array and I have double the items I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a `foreach()` to inject the `data`. To directly modify array elements of `$arr2` within the loop we precede `$value` with `&`, so the value is assigned by reference:

```
<?php
$arr1 = [
  ['data' => 'DFF022',],
  ['data' => 'DFF026',],
];

$arr2 = [
    [
        'number' => 'INC0000002',
        'ia' => '',
        'description' => 'Printer not working',
        'state' => 'Monitoring - Waiting for Client',
        'updated' => '12/30/2020 19.09.01',
        'opened' => '12/24/2020 20.35.36',
    ],
    [
        'number' => 'INC0000003',
        'ia' => '',
        'description' => 'Monitor broke down',
        'state' => 'Pending - Awaiting Change Approval/Implementation',
        'updated' => '12/29/2020 23.57.06',
        'opened' => '12/29/2020 08.21.38',
    ],
];

foreach($arr2 as $key => &$value) {
    $value['data'] = $arr1[$key]['data'];
}
```

Output (`print_r($arr2)`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [number] => INC0000002
            [ia] => 
            [description] => Printer not working
            [state] => Monitoring - Waiting for Client
            [updated] => 12/30/2020 19.09.01
            [opened] => 12/24/2020 20.35.36
            [data] => DFF022
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [number] => INC0000003
            [ia] => 
            [description] => Monitor broke down
            [state] => Pending - Awaiting Change Approval/Implementation
            [updated] => 12/29/2020 23.57.06
            [opened] => 12/29/2020 08.21.38
            [data] => DFF026
        )

)
```

working [demo](https://3v4l.org/AnhuO)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much!! Learned something else today :)

Comment: Glad I could help!